# Kill proces if events received or if timeout

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I have a child who runs a process with execl and a parent that waits for it. If I receive a stopEvent (implemented with a pipe2 and poll) the child is killed. If the child runs the process for more than 10 minutes (monitore with sigtimedwait) the child is killed. If I try to implement both poll and sigtimedwait and I receive a stopEvent the child continues to run for 10 minutes, then is closed. 
Does anyone knows a mor efficient way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

[`poll`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) has a timeout parameter.  This seems easier to manage than a poll and a signal.

Comment: I know, but I have 2 tipes of events which are independent one from another: stopEvent and timeout. In the parent I've started a separate thread which waits for the timeout event.

Comment: Can you send the signal that the parent waits for from within the child when it is finished, signalling that the parent can stop waiting?  It is a bit more overkill than letting the child do the timeout.